# Particular solution of 1st ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

for the first order liner ODE
$$u'+\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)u=\frac{e^x (1-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x})}{2x}$$
That the IF is 
$$e^{\int{\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)}dx}=e^{\ln x-\ln \sin x}=\frac{x}{\sin x}$$

and does the particular solution should be

$$u_p=e^{-{\int{\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)}}dx}\int{e^{\int{\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)}dx}{\frac{e^x (1-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x})}{2x}}}dx=\frac{\sin x}{x} \int{\frac{e^x}{2}{\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\right)}}dx$$

where ... is it solvable...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as:
$$-e^x\frac{(1-\cot x)}{2x}+\left(\frac1x-\cot x\right)u+u'=0$$
Let 
$$R(x,u)=\left(\frac1x-\cot x\right)u-e^x\frac{(1-\cot x)}{2x}\\
S(x,u)=1$$
This is not an exact equation, because:
$$\frac{\partial R(x,u)}{\partial u}=\frac1x-\cot x\ne0=\frac{\partial S(x,u)}{\partial x}$$
Now find an integrating factor $\mu(x)$ such that:
$$\mu(x)R(x,u)+\mu(x)\frac{du(x)}{dx}S(x,u)=0\text{ is exact}$$
This means $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial u}R(x,u)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu(x)S(x,\mu))$:
$$\left(\frac1x-\cot x\right)\mu(x)=\frac{d\mu(x)}{dx}$$
Isolate $\mu(x)$ to the left-hand side:
$$\frac{\large \frac{\partial \mu(x)}{\partial x}}{\mu(x)}=\frac{d\mu(x)}{dx}$$
Integrate both sides wrt x:
$$\ln(\mu(x))=\ln(x)-\ln(\sin x)$$
Take exponentials of both sides:
$$\mu(x)=x\csc x$$
Multiply both sides of $\displaystyle u'+\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)u-\frac{e^x (1-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x})}{2x}=0$ by $\mu(x)$:
$$\frac12\csc(x)(-e^x+\cot (x)(e^x-2xu(x))+2u(x))+(x\csc x)\frac{du(x)}{dx}=0$$
Let $P(x,u)=\frac12\csc(x)(-e^x+\cot (x)(e^x-2xu(x))+2u(x))$ and $Q(x,u)=x\csc x$.This is an exact equation, because
$$\frac{\partial P(x\mu)}{\partial u}=\frac12(2-2x\cot x)\csc x=\frac{\partial Q(x\mu)}{\partial x}$$
Define $f(x,u)$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f(x\mu)}{\partial x}=P(x,u)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x\mu)}{\partial u}=Q(x,u)$ Then the solution will be given by $$f(x,u)=c_1\text{ where $c_1$ is an arbitary constant}$$
Integrate $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x\mu)}{\partial u}$ wrt x in order to find $f(x,u)$:
$$f(x,u)=\int\frac12\csc x(-e^x+2u+\cot x(e^x-2ux))dx=-\frac12(\csc x(e^x-2ux))+g(u)\text{ where g(u) is an arbitary function of u}$$
Diffrentiate $f(x,u)$ wrt u in order to find $g(u)$:
$$\frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(-\frac12(\csc x(e^x-2ux))+g(u))=x\csc x+\frac{dg(u)}{du}$$
Substitute into $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial u}=Q(x,u)$:
$$x\csc x+\frac{dg(u)}{du}=x\csc x$$
Solve for $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(x\mu)}{\partial u}$
$$\frac{\partial f(x\mu)}{\partial u}=0$$
Integrate $\frac{\partial f(x\mu)}{\partial u}$ wrt u:
$$g(u)=\int0du=0$$
Substitute $g(u)$ into $f(x,u)$:
$$f(x,u)=1\frac12(\csc x(e^x-2ux))$$
The solution is $f(x,u)=c_1$:
$$-\frac12(\csc x(e^x-2ux))=c_1$$
Solve for u:
$$u(x)=\frac{e^x+2c_1\sin x}{2x}$$
Simplify the arbitary constants:
$$\boxed{\LARGE \text{ Answer: } u(x)=\frac{e^x}{2x}+\frac{c_1\sin x}x}$$

Answer (score 1):

You properly found that the solution of $$u'+\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)u=0$$ is $$u=C \frac{\sin (x)}{x}$$ Now, for $$u'+\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)u=\frac{e^x (1-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x})}{2x}$$ consider than the solution is $$u=C(x) \frac{\sin (x)}{x}$$ Differentiate, replace and simplify. You should arrive to $$\frac{2 \sin (x) C'(x)+e^x (\cot (x)-1)}{2 x}=0$$ that is to say $$C'(x)=-\frac{1}{2} e^x (\cot (x)-1) \csc (x)$$ from which $$C(x)=\frac{1}{2} e^x \csc (x)+K$$ and so, finally $$u=K\frac{ \sin (x)}{x}+\frac{e^x}{2 x}$$

Comment: I think here $C'(x)$ is the same as the end of my last equation where $$\int{\frac{e^x}{2}{\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\right)}}dx$$ and which is hard to integral